# Focus New Tab's Textarea Bootstrap 3 + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some Bootstrap toggleable tabs which each contain a textarea. I have it set up so you can make a new tabs that contain textareas. However, when this new tab is created, I want the textarea inside of it focused with the cursor.

Here is the relevant problem code with a slightly larger fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1390/
For the fiddle it should focus the textarea after the first item is created.

```
function ListController($scope, topics) {

    var currentId = 0;
    $scope.mainList = topics;

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        topics.push({
            id: (currentId++),
            active: "active",
            name: $scope.newItem,
        });

        //clears input box
        $scope.newItem = "";

        //remove previous bootstrap active classes
        $('ul.nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab-content .tab-pane.active').removeClass('active');   

        //Can't get this part to work!!
        //(the textareas have dynamic id's)
        $('#textarea0').focus();
    }
}
```

What is frustrating is that I can focus the textarea if I create a button and have it focus directly, outside of the controller. (There's an example in the fiddle). This leads me to believe I'm trying to focus the textarea before it's actually getting created but I tried doing a callback function and that wasn't working either - maybe I screwed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular recommends that you not do DOM manipulation inside controllers.  The line is blurrier here since you're technically doing the manipulation in the directive, but using a controller function to do it.  I'd personally avoid that.

In either case, one advantage of doing this in the directive is it gives you easy access to `element`.  And that makes it easy to use jQlite which is Angular aware vs jQuery.

So I'd delete this line in your controller that's causing you trouble: `$('#textarea0').focus();`

And, instead, add this jQlite line to your directive:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#textarea0')).focus();
```

So your directive now looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('ngEnter', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });
                angular.element(document.querySelector('#textarea0')).focus();

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

That resolves your issue:  [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1396/)

But I'd also move the two `removeClass` lines into your directive and use jQlite instead there too- if it was me.  Then your controller function can focus on list related tasks while the directive handles the DOM.

Comment: I appreciate your insight on better Angular practices. I just started using Angular so that was a very useful answer. The only problem with this solution is that since I dynamically id the textarea's upon creation, I have to select them with $('#textarea' + currentId) yet currentId is scoped within the controller. I obviously can move it outside of the controller and give it a wider scope, but that feels wrong to me and probably isn't best pracitce. Is there a better, more Angular way to solve that problem?

Comment: If I'm following you, you could have `addItem` return `currentId` - so it would be available inside your directive for use in the `querySelector()`

Comment: Here's an example of that:  http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1397/  (I didn't use currentId- but you'll see how the returned value comes through)